# How do optimize in the image space using tensorflow graphics?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, graphics, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to setup a toy problem which replicates the 3rd figure on this site:
https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics/overview

As shown, the loss function is between 2 images.  How does one set up such a problem?

I went through each tensorflow colab notebook on their github site very carefully.  There are 2 examples that come close to what I trying to do, the first is the 6dof estimate and the 2nd is the camera intrinsics estimate.  However, both of these problems are optimized over vertices using the l2 norm.  How do I get tensorflow graphics to render the hypothesized object and perform the difference between the 2 images (ground truth and tfg rendered).  A small toy example would be very helpful especially since figure 3 of the tfg site shows this very example.

EDIT 1:  After some research, it appears the thing I am looking for is a differentiable rasterizer.  I use the rasterizer to synthesize the scene to an image (a 2d map).  After I have that image, I can difference it with my ground truth (using my favorite function like l2norm, l1norm, or differentiable ssim).  Does tensorflow graphics have a differentiable rasterizer?

Comment: I'd like to learn to write better questions.  How can I improve this one?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you have to compute the rays and then compute the irradiance. You can do this by using a meshgrid of rays which are emitted from each virtual pixel.

However, note that the rasterizer, although differentiable, will not support shadowing.  Facets along with a bdrf are used in the tensorflow graphics samples (e.g. the sphere and cow) to deal with occlusion.